# Rank-one Update to a Rank Revealing QR (RRQR) Factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we are given an RRQR factorization for some matrix $A∈\mathbb{R}^{m×n} , A\Pi=QR$ where $m>n$. Is there a cheap way to update $A′=A+uv^{\top}$ given this factorization?

I am aware of how to update the QR factorization given a rank-one update, but I am unsure how to update the permuation matrix $\Pi$ accordingly to guarantee the rank-revealing aspect.

xposted https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24373/rank-one-update-to-a-rank-revealing-qr-rrqr-factorization